# Border de diferentes cores

Tags: html, css

Quero que meu texto fique com as bordas da seguinte forma:

Topo: preto
Laterais: Cinza

Segue exemplo de como gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue imagem até onde consegui. Como faço para a borda de cima ficar preta e aumentar as distancias das laterais do texto ? Segue HTML e CSS que estou utilizando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.explicacao_produto{
 border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
margin-left: 10px;
}
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="explicacao_produto">
                       <h2>Bermuda Lacoste</h2>
                       <p>texto</p>

                       <h4 class="dimensao">Dimensões</h4>
                       <p>- Altura: 9,5cm</p>
                       <p>- Diâmetro: 8cm</p>
                       <p>- Capacidade: 300ml</p>
                       </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Manipular as bordas com css:**

Ao adicionar bordas aos elementos de sua página, você tem a opção de manipular individualmente cada segmento dessa borda *(top,right,left,bottom)*.

Manipulando as bordas de cima e de baixo:

```
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

Manipulando as bordas laterais:

```
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
```

Para aumentar a distância interna do elemento utilizamos o `padding`

```
padding: 5px;
```

A propriedade `padding` também pode ser manipulada por cada segmento do objeto *(top,right,left,bottom)*.

> Não sei se ja é do seu conhecimento, mas o site [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)
>   fornece grande ajuda neste tipo de aprendizado.

Confira [este](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) exemplo de tutorial sobre bordas no site do W3.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `border-right-color` e `border-left-color` para as verticais e `border-bottom-color` e `border-top-color` para as  você controla melhor qual a cor de cada borda. A distancia entre o texto e a borda você usa o `padding`.